# Is there an idiomatic way to malloc and memcpy a struct?

Tags: go, malloc

In plain C, if I want a shallow heap copy of a struct, I would `malloc()` and `memcpy()` it.

In Go, I guess I have to do something like this:

```golang
original := Data{...}
copy := &Data{}     // malloc
*copy = original    // memcpy
```

But it doesn't look nice to me, nor idiomatic. What's the "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to do a simple assignment and let the compiler allocate `copy` on the heap after performing escape analysis:

```
original := Data{...}
copy := original
return &copy  // Or call some function with &copy as a parameter
```

Upon noticing that `copy` is used by reference and outlives the stack, Go will automatically allocate it on the heap rather than on the stack (the copy is still done properly of course)

**We effectively no longer care about the heap, letting the compiler allocate it there as needed based on escape analysis. Our only concern is the copy itself.**

You can see an example in action on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nMKnoj):

Given the following simple code:

```golang
func main() {
   type Data struct{
        foo string
    }

    original := Data{"hi"}
    copy := original
    copyPtr := &copy
    fmt.Println(copyPtr)
}
```

Go will automatically allocate `copy` on the heap:

```
        call    runtime.newobject(SB)
```

We can also see this in action by passing extra flags at compile time showing escape and inlining decisions:

```
$ go build -gcflags '-m' .
...
./main.go:11:2: moved to heap: copy
...
```

**Note**: [copy](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) is a builtin function. It might be a good idea to avoid reusing the name (it works just fine, but it's not great practice).

Answer (score 2):

A struct variable in Golang can be copied to another simply by an assignment statement:

https://play.golang.org/p/4Zcbxhy5UoB

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    name string
}

func main() {
    u1 := User{name: "foo"}
    
    u2 := u1
    u2.name = "bar"
    
    fmt.Println("u1: ", u1)
    fmt.Println("u2: ", u2)

}
```

output:

```
u1:  {foo}
u2:  {bar}
```