# golang struct creation return different memory addresses

Tags: go

I'm having trouble understanding why golang returns a different memory address on what appears to be the same struct (maybe it's not, perhaps it copies with the same values to another memory address?).

Here's the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Creature struct {
    Name    string
    isAlive bool
}

func foo() Creature {
    myCreature := Creature{Name: "dino", isAlive: true}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &myCreature)
    fmt.Println(myCreature)
    return myCreature
}

func main() {
    myCreat := foo()
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &myCreat)
    fmt.Println(myCreat)
}
```

The output of the code is the following

```
0xc000004090
{dino true}
0xc000004078
{dino true}
```

As you can see, the memory addresses are different. Why?
Should I instead return a memory address?

Comment: foo() returns a struct (not a pointer), and `myCreat := foo()` copies the struct.

Comment: But note also that this struct is pretty tiny, and the cost of copying the struct may be lower than the cost of using a pointer. One of the general rules of Go is not to start using pointers if it's not required by the algorithm or already shown to help by real-world profiling.

Comment: It's also neat to see how the call to `foo` increases the stack pointer (I don't know exactly hoe Go is implemented, but usually the stack has parameters and the return address) - this is mainly why you're seeing different values.  I thinks is will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234487/returning-a-pointer-on-stack -

Comment: @Kobi so using functions like malloc make no sense in golang?

Comment: Yep. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518223/is-there-an-idiomatic-way-to-malloc-and-memcpy-a-struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having trouble understanding why golang returns a different memory address on what appears to be the same struct (maybe it's not, perhaps it copies with the same values to another memory address?).

You didn't return a memory address, you returned a struct.

> As you can see, the memory addresses are different.

Because you returned a struct and it was copied to a new one.

> Why? Should I instead return a memory address?

Yes, if you want a pointer then return that.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Creature struct {
    Name    string
    isAlive bool
}

func foo() *Creature {
    myCreature := Creature{Name: "dino", isAlive: true}
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &myCreature)
    fmt.Println(myCreature)
    return &myCreature
}

func main() {
    myCreat := foo()
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", myCreat)
    fmt.Println(*myCreat)
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6f7dJ2b5d0P)

The rule in Go is that you only use pointers when you actually need them, when you have to modify a struct's values or something. You should not use pointers because you think it might be more efficient. The memory optimiser can do its work more efficiently if you don't force it to do things one way or another.

See https://medium.com/@vCabbage/go-are-pointers-a-performance-optimization-a95840d3ef85, https://betterprogramming.pub/why-you-should-avoid-pointers-in-go-36724365a2a7, and many more articles.